# Laravel rate limit to return a JSON payload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm building an API on top of Laravel. I'd like to use the built in rate limiting capabilities by using the `Throttle` middleware.

Problem is, when the throttle middleware triggers the response is:

```
// Response headers
Too Many Attempts.
```

My API uses an error payload in JSON that looks like the following:

```
// Response headers
{
  "status": "error",
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Resource not found."
  }
}
```

What is the best way to get the `Throttle` middleware to return an output in the manner I require?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make your own shiny middleware, extend it by original, and override methods you like to be overriden.

```
$ php artisan make:middleware ThrottleRequests
```

Open up **kernel.php** and remove (comment out) original middleware and add yours.

*ThrottleRequests.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ThrottleRequests extends \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests
{
    protected function buildResponse($key, $maxAttempts)
    {
        return parent::buildResponse($key, $maxAttempts); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

*kernel.php*

```
.
.
.
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    //'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    //'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'throttle' => \App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class
];
```

Comment: Note that in Laravel 5.6 there's no `buildResponse()` in the base class, but this was still very helpful - I overrode `handle()`.

Comment: @JanŻankowski thanks, I will add the note (or you may edit the question yourself) the question is tagged with 5.3, so do not edit the code example; just add the note.

Answer (score 4):

I know it is a very old question but I have a very short solution for this problem.

Instead of creating new middleware, we can catch and handle the ThrottleRequestsException inside the Handler.php and return the JSON response accordingly.

***app\Exceptions\Hanlder.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof ThrottleRequestsException && $request->wantsJson()) {
            return json_encode([
                'message' => 'Too many attempts, please slow down the request.',
                'status' => false
            ]);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file **ApiThrottleRequests.php** in **app/Http/Middleware/** and paste the code below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ApiThrottleRequests
{
/**
 * The rate limiter instance.
 *
 * @var \Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter
 */
protected $limiter;

/**
 * Create a new request throttler.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter $limiter
 */
public function __construct(RateLimiter $limiter)
{
    $this->limiter = $limiter;
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param  \Closure $next
 * @param  int $maxAttempts
 * @param  int $decayMinutes
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $maxAttempts = 60, $decayMinutes = 1)
{
    $key = $this->resolveRequestSignature($request);

    if ($this->limiter->tooManyAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $decayMinutes)) {
        return $this->buildResponse($key, $maxAttempts);
    }

    $this->limiter->hit($key, $decayMinutes);

    $response = $next($request);

    return $this->addHeaders(
        $response, $maxAttempts,
        $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts)
    );
}

/**
 * Resolve request signature.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return string
 */
protected function resolveRequestSignature($request)
{
    return $request->fingerprint();
}

/**
 * Create a 'too many attempts' response.
 *
 * @param  string $key
 * @param  int $maxAttempts
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function buildResponse($key, $maxAttempts)
{
    $message = json_encode([
        'error' => [
            'message' => 'Too many attempts, please slow down the request.' //may comes from lang file
        ],
        'status' => 4029 //your custom code
    ]);

    $response = new Response($message, 429);

    $retryAfter = $this->limiter->availableIn($key);

    return $this->addHeaders(
        $response, $maxAttempts,
        $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $retryAfter),
        $retryAfter
    );
}

/**
 * Add the limit header information to the given response.
 *
 * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response
 * @param  int $maxAttempts
 * @param  int $remainingAttempts
 * @param  int|null $retryAfter
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function addHeaders(Response $response, $maxAttempts, $remainingAttempts, $retryAfter = null)
{
    $headers = [
        'X-RateLimit-Limit' => $maxAttempts,
        'X-RateLimit-Remaining' => $remainingAttempts,
    ];

    if (!is_null($retryAfter)) {
        $headers['Retry-After'] = $retryAfter;
        $headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    }

    $response->headers->add($headers);

    return $response;
}

/**
 * Calculate the number of remaining attempts.
 *
 * @param  string $key
 * @param  int $maxAttempts
 * @param  int|null $retryAfter
 * @return int
 */
protected function calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $retryAfter = null)
{
    if (!is_null($retryAfter)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $this->limiter->retriesLeft($key, $maxAttempts);
}
```

}

Then go to your **kernel.php** file in **app/Http/** directory and replace

```
'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
```

with

```
'throttle' => \App\Middleware\ApiThrottleRequests::class,
```

and use it

```
middleware('throttle:60,1')
```

or add

```
'apiThrottle' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApiThrottleRequests::class,
```

and you use this way

```
middleware('apiThrottle:60,1')
```

and help link

https://thedevsaddam.gitbooks.io/off-time-story/how_to_customize_laravel_throttle_message_response.html

Answer (score 1):

So what I did was create a custom middleware that extends the ThrottleRequest middleware. You can override the handle function to check the request and see if it expects JSON as a response. If so, call the buildJsonResponse function which will format a JSON 429 response. You can tailor the JsonResponse in buildJsonResponse to suit your API needs.

This allows your throttle middleware to handle both JSON and other responses. If the request is expecting JSON, it will return a JSON response, but otherwise, it will return the standard "Too Many Attempts" plaintext response.

Please note this came from the Laravel 5.6.x `ThrottleRequests` middleware, and it is possible that the base class has changed since then.

**EDIT:**
Fixed call to the wrong method in the case where the request isn't expecting JSON response, but the request is throttled. Should be `$this->buildException($key, $maxAttempts);` not `$this->buildResponse($key, $maxAttempts);`

```
<?php



namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests;

class ThrottlesRequest extends ThrottleRequests
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  int  $maxAttempts
     * @param  float|int  $decayMinutes
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $maxAttempts = 60, $decayMinutes = 1)
    {
        $key = $this->resolveRequestSignature($request);

        if ($this->limiter->tooManyAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $decayMinutes)) {
            // If the request expects JSON, build a JSON response, otherwise build standard response
            if ($request->expectsJson()) {
                return $this->buildJsonResponse($key, $maxAttempts);
            } else {
                return $this->buildException($key, $maxAttempts);
            }
        }

        $this->limiter->hit($key, $decayMinutes);

        $response = $next($request);

        return $this->addHeaders(
            $response, $maxAttempts,
            $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create a 'too many attempts' JSON response.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  int  $maxAttempts
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function buildJsonResponse($key, $maxAttempts)
    {
        $response = new JsonResponse([
            'error' => [
                'code' => 429,
                'message' => 'Too Many Attempts.',
            ],
        ], 429);

        $retryAfter = $this->limiter->availableIn($key);

        return $this->addHeaders(
            $response, $maxAttempts,
            $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $retryAfter),
            $retryAfter
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: it will throw an error  `"Call to undefined method App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::buildResponse()"`

Comment: Yeah good catch. It's supposed to be `return $this->buildException($key, $maxAttempts);`. Also note this was written for Laravel 5.6.x so it is possible the base `ThrottleRequests` class has changed in newer Laravel versions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on laravel 8:

```
 RateLimiter::for("verify",function(Request $request){
        return Limit::perMinute(2)->by($request->ip())->response(function(){
            return response()->json(["state"=>false,"error"=>"Youve tried too many times"],200);
        });
    });
```

And then add the throttle middleware to your route